# Absolutely Position a Division in a Relative Manner

Tags: css, position, positioning, css-position

I am not too sure how to word what my question but these are my thoughts:

**What I Understand:** given that div-B is nested within div-A...

I can set relative positioning on div-A so that any elements within div-A will be positioned relative to div-A. And then, if I set absolute positioning on div-B, I can move it to the top right corner of div-A.

```
#div-A {
 position:relative;
}
#div-B {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
}
```

Additionally, if i remove the div-A portion and leave just...

```
#div-B {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:0;
}
```

div-B will position itself in the upper-right corner of the window or the first relatively positioned container that it is contained inside.

**My Question:** Seeing that divisions within a relatively positioned container can be placed at that containers bounds using absolute positioning, is there a way to absolutely position a division but have that same division treat the elements contained inside of it in a relative manner? That is, is it possible to absolutely position a container and have its contained elements be absolutely positioned relative to itself?

Comment: Elements in an absolutely-positioned wrapper become part of the normal document flow within that wrapper. I think you may need a diagram to explain what you need.

Comment: An absolute parent will act as a positioning anchor point for absolutely positioned children.  So for example if you want to absolutely position a parent to the top right corner and then position a child to the bottom left corner of your parent you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid positioning doesn't work exactly as you might think it does. `position: relative;` pertains to the element itself, not to positioning of the nested elements (unless you use `position: inherit;` in the child elements). See [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#choose-position) at W3.org.